# How to combine feature_columns, model_to_estimator and dataset API in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have a toy example in tensorflow using the high-level APIs: `tf.estimator`, `tf.data` and `tf.feature_column`. I would like to swap the canned estimator with a keras model using the `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`. I can generate an estimator from the keras model, but then the I get an error regarding the names and shapes of the input. I think the input shape of the keras model is wrong because the `input_fn` passes all of the data, and not the feature columns. In other words I'm not sure how to connect the feature columns to the keras model

Here are the relevant parts of the **code that works**:

```
...
col1 = categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('col1', [1, 2, 3])
col1_ind = C.indicator_column(col1)

col2 = numeric_column('col2')

...

estimator = E.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[col1_ind, col2],
    hidden_units=[10])

...

def input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = D.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features),
                                            labels))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
return dataset

...

train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

I encounter the problem if I try to swap the `DNNClassifier` with something like:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(L.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim=9))
....

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

estimator = model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
```

In this case I get the following error message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after 600 secs (eval_spec.throttle_secs) or training is finished.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-0242f6f379fc> in <module>()
----> 1 E.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py in train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
    437         '(with task id 0).  Given task id {}'.format(config.task_id))
    438 
--> 439   executor.run()
    440 
    441 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py in run(self)
    516         config.task_type != run_config_lib.TaskType.EVALUATOR):
    517       logging.info('Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).')
--> 518       self.run_local()
    519       return
    520 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py in run_local(self)
    648           input_fn=self._train_spec.input_fn,
    649           max_steps=self._train_spec.max_steps,
--> 650           hooks=train_hooks)
    651 
    652       # Final export signal: For any eval result with global_step >= train

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    353 
    354     saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 355     loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    356     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    357     return self

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    822       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
    823       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
--> 824           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
    825 
    826       if self._warm_start_settings:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
    803 
    804     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
--> 805     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
    806     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
    807 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py in model_fn(features, labels, mode)
    317     """model_fn for keras Estimator."""
    318     model = _clone_and_build_model(mode, keras_model, custom_objects, features,
--> 319                                    labels)
    320     # Get inputs to EstimatorSpec
    321     predictions = dict(zip(model.output_names, model.outputs))

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py in _clone_and_build_model(mode, keras_model, custom_objects, features, labels)
    251     input_tensors = _create_ordered_io(keras_model,
    252                                        estimator_io=features,
--> 253                                        is_input=True)
    254   # Get list of outputs.
    255   if labels is None:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py in _create_ordered_io(keras_model, estimator_io, is_input)
     94             'It needs to match one '
     95             'of the following: %s' % ('input' if is_input else 'output', key,
---> 96                                       ', '.join(keras_io_names)))
     97       tensors = [_cast_tensor_to_floatx(estimator_io[io_name])
     98                  for io_name in keras_io_names]

ValueError: Cannot find input with name "col1" in Keras Model. It needs to match one of the following: dense_1_input
```

Answer (score 2):

To connect the `feature_columns` with the estimator created via `model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)`, you have to make the name of the feature_column match the name of the input layer of your model.

For example, your `input_fn()` could look like this:

```
def input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = D.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    tf.add_to_collection(
        tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return {"dense_1_input": features}, labels
```

So, whatever name your input layer has, the keras model expects a feature column of that name with `_input` added:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(L.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim=9, name="MY_NAME"))

def input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    ...
    return {"MY_NAME_input": features}, labels
```

Answer (score 0):

Some example codes:

```
from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_v2 as fc

feature_layer = fc.FeatureLayer(your_feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

please refer to [feature_cols_keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/b4d8d7096099c2b0a7df6a0564bf6eca8c96c4a0/site/en/tutorials/structured_data/feature_cols_keras.ipynb)